# Calling function into map reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to call a function inside the map into the dom. This is an example:

Which syntax should I use? 
Sorry but I'm a beginner with react and I'm trying. 
Which is the best way?

````
 {rows.map((row) =>                           
   <tr>   
     <td>{row.notime}</td>
       {columns.map((col) =>        
        function here <-------------                    
         (
          <td>
            <Slot appuntamenti={appuntamento(col.datacorrente row.oracorrente)} />
          </td>
           )
    ```
````

Comment: The syntax is just regular javascript syntax, have you even tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can call any function you want inside your map and before the return like this:

```
{columns.map((col) => {
    doSomething(col);
    return (
        <td>
            <Slot ... />
        </td>
    )
})
```